# How can an app be unsupported in google play even if the apk says it's compatible

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app in Google play.

According to the Developer Console, all devices are supported.

Supported devices
7651

Excluded devices
0

Yet, the app is unsupported for for example Asus ME302C.

Here is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="NaN" android:versionName="1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.zenconomy.kvittoScanner" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="HelloCordova" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does the tablet has two camera or just the front one?
"Excluded devices 0" means that you do not explicitly exclude any devices, but for some devices (for example for the Nexus 7 2012) if you do not specify that rear camera is not needed you do not see the app for that device on Play Store.

Comment: To bettter answer your question, can you post what permissions and features your app uses from your AndroidManifest.xml